# Daily Dilbert strip served by https

Tags: ssl

I have a web site which embeds the Daily Dilbert comic strip by parsing it from the RSS feed that dilbert.com publishes, but said website is SSL encrypted, and the image as published is not.  This triggers a mixed content warning in Internet Explorer.

I don't want to have to pull it down once a day and serve it locally if I can help - does anyone have a link to a publicly available daily Dilbert which I can fetch with an SSL (https) URL?

**Edit:** I hadn't thought of proxying it myself (thanks splattne!) which solves it neatly:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dilbert-proxy/
    RewriteRule ^/dilbert-proxy/(.*)$ http://dilbert.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Are you legaly allowed to redistribute the comic?

Comment: I feel that displaying it off their site (consuming their public RSS) is better manners than saving a copy and redistributing.

Comment: 65 views and not one of you thought it was a concise and well written question worthy of an upvote? ;)

Comment: I would strongly argue from their terms of use (http://dilbert.com/terms/) that it is a result of standard search engine or internet browser usage linking to the original. It is arguably non standard to embed (as it is non trivial to do), and clearly illegal to copy and display/redistribute your own copy.

Comment: Thanks, I have e-mailled them to clarify.  There are a lot of widgets that display the Daily Dilbert comic on the web, and while that doesn't necessarily make what I am doing here any more right, it does lean towards 'acceptable' or 'we turn a blind eye'.

Comment: The reason I called it "bad manners" is that by proxying their image, you're amplifying traffic.  Each request to you server is generating a second request from theirs.  Since you don't know what their bandwidth charges are, you could be costing them real $$, depending on the traffic flow you see.  Serving the image locally is also more robust and speedier, and will end up generating a better user experience for visitors to your site.  It's not that hard to generate a script to fetch the image once a day, and will be better in the long run.

Comment: @Troggy: Redistributing single lawfully-made copies is always legal -- it's making additional copies that requires permission. His proxy always gets a copy from a lawful source and then gives that single copy to someone else without him retaining it. That's just as legal as giving a book to a friend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Let's pretend you've got the permission from Scott Adams or whoever owns the rights of the Dilbert strips.*

You could do some **reverse proxying**, creating a rule for a fictive URL on your site, let's say a request

```
https://www.example.com/dilbert/strip.gif
```

which triggers your reverse proxy mechanism to fetch the image from the dilbert.com site

```
http://www.dilbert.com/..../strip.gif
```

and sending the response from your server with the content fetched from the Dilbert server. This way you can keep the SSL connection, because it's transparent for the user.

Depending on your platform you'll have to see your options for using a revery proxy mechanism.

Comment: +1 Now we're thinking.  This is Apache2 on Debian (was tossing up between serverfault and superuser for the question).

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have permission from the site owners at Daily Dilbert, I'd suggest doing exactly that - make a local copy and serve it yourself.  Serving the image on your page off their servers is bad web manners.

Comment: ...though to copy the image one may also need permission.

Comment: That is exactly what their RSS feed does.  I am simply a feed reader displaying that that, minus the other n-1 days.

Comment: No, you're not. Their RSS feed is handled by feedburner.com and I guess there's a reason for that.